# Python Tkinter finding the average of star rating user button click

Tags: python, tkinter, button, events, average

I am really new to python and Tkinter but I am trying to make
[this GUI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0M7I.png)

It is essentially a star rating system that contains 5 buttons from 1-5. The user has to click the rating button they would like to enter and it should average out the star rating based on the previous button clicks.

This is the code I have so far but I'm stuck with how to make the average from the button click events.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
    from tkinter import *
    ws = Tk()
    ws.title("Cleanliness Rater")
    ws.geometry("500x500")

Label(ws, text="Please rate the cleanliness of this bus: ", font=("arial ", 12) ).pack()


Label(ws, text="):", font=("arial ", 12) ).pack()

one = Button(ws, text="1", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

two = Button(ws, text="2", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

three = Button(ws, text="3", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

four = Button(ws, text="4", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

five = Button(ws, text="5", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

Label(ws, text="(:", font=("arial ", 12) ).pack()


ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you suing duplicate padx=5, pady=10? You should remove it.

Comment: You want same layout as image? in horizontal? You should remove this one = and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `StringVar()` ([here](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-stringvar/)'s a article about it)  and [functions](https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/) or [lambdas](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/) to do this.

First we'll keep a track of sum of all total rating in a variable named `count` and total number of increments in a variable named `increments`

Calculating Average rating from here would be fairly easy, it'd be `count/increments`

Then we'll create a `StringVar()` to keep track of the label text since it'd be dynamic. We'll initially set it to "Unrated".

```py
count = 0
ans = StringVar(ws)
ans.set("Unrated")
increments = 0
```

Then we'll have a function that increments the count variable and the increment counter for us, it'd also change the label text, the StringVar.

```py
def increment_count(x):
    global count,increments,ans
    count += x
    increments+=1
    ans.set(str(count/increments))
```

Assign the commands to each buttons.

```py
Button(ws, ... ,command = lambda:increment_count(1)).pack(padx=5, pady=10)
```

And we're done!

```py
from tkinter import *
ws = Tk()
ws.title("Cleanliness Rater")
ws.geometry("500x500")

Label(ws, text="Please rate the cleanliness of this bus: ", font=("arial ", 12) ).pack()


Label(ws, text="):", font=("arial ", 12) ).pack()


count = 0
ans = StringVar(ws)
ans.set("Unrated")
increments = 0

def increment_count(x):
    global count,increments,ans
    count += x
    increments+=1
    ans.set(str(count/increments))

one = Button(ws, text="1", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10,command = lambda:increment_count(1)).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

two = Button(ws, text="2", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10,command=lambda:increment_count(2)).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

three = Button(ws, text="3", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10,command=lambda:increment_count(3)).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

four = Button(ws, text="4", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10,command=lambda:increment_count(4)).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

five = Button(ws, text="5", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10,command=lambda:increment_count(5)).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

Label(ws, text="(:", font=("arial ", 12) ).pack()

Label(ws,textvariable=ans).pack()
ws.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to have command associated with your button, i used partial to pass an argument to the function.
Update me if this runs fine.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
ws = Tk()
ws.title("Cleanliness Rater")
ws.geometry("500x500")
score = []



total_rating = 0
def calculate(x):
    
    global score 
    score.append(x)
    total_rating = sum(score)/len(score)
    print(total_rating)
    #Label2(ws, text="Please rate the cleanliness rating till now: "+total_rating, font=("arial ", 12) ).pack()
    
Label(ws, text="Please rate the cleanliness of this bus: ", font=("arial ", 12) ).pack()


Label(ws, text="):", font=("arial ", 12) ).pack()

one = Button(ws,command = partial(calculate, 1), text="1", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

two = Button(ws,command = partial(calculate, 2), text="2", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

three = Button(ws,command = partial(calculate, 3), text="3", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

four = Button(ws,command = partial(calculate, 4), text="4", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

five = Button(ws,command = partial(calculate, 5), text="5", borderwidth=3, relief="raised", padx=5, pady=10).pack(padx=5, pady=10)

Label(ws, text="(:", font=("arial ", 12) ).pack()


ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, its so helpful and I got it to work perfectly. I'm very grateful for your advice and explanation.

Comment: Would be great if you mark this as correct.